# Proving the sum of two vectors lies in the same plane as those vectors being added.

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $V_1$ and $V_2$ are any two vectors with the same initial point and $k_1, k_2$ are any two scalars, prove that $k_1V_1+k_2V_2$ lies in the same plane as $V_1$ and $V_2$.

I'm not sure if I'm going about this correctly, but I'll give it a shot.

*Proof.* Since $V_1$ and $V_2$ share the same initial point, say $O$, we have $k_1V_1$ and $k_2V_2$ share the same initial point $O$. Let $k_1V1 = \vec{OQ}$ and $k_2V_2 = \vec{OP}$. Then
$$
k_1V_1+k_2V_2 = \vec{OP}+\vec{OQ} \tag1
$$

This sum is defined by constructing a vector $\vec{PR}=\vec{OQ}$ which uniquely determines the point $R$, and thus the resultant vector of $(1)$ is $\vec{OR}$.

If $\vec{OP}$ and $\vec{OQ}$ do not lie in the same straight line, then we have parallelogram $OQRP$, with $\vec{OR}$ lying in the diagonal of $OQRP$.  And so

$$
\vec{OR} = \vec{OP}+\vec{OQ} = k_1V_1+k_2V_2
$$

lies in parallelogram $OQRP$ as do vectors $V_1$ and $V_2$.

Similar conclusion if $\vec{OP}$ and $\vec{OQ}$ do lie in the same straight line.

---

Have I done anything here? Please help.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You have obviously done something. Please edit your post and make your question clearer. Do you by any chance mean "Have I done anything wrong here?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a normal vector Ñ defining the plane of interest(P) such that: Ñ•V¹ = O and  Ñ•V² = O.
For any vector V to lie in plane P, V•Ñ = O.
Considering V=k¹V¹+k²V²,
(k¹V¹+k²V²)•Ñ = k¹(V¹•Ñ)+k²(V²•Ñ) = k¹(0) + k²(0) = 0,
Implying that our desired vector lies in P